# Sourcing works manually but fails when done from script

Tags: bash, shell-script, alias, source

Using `curl` as in:

```
bash <(curl -s https://raw.githubusercontent.com/user/repo/master/script.sh | tr -d '\r')
```

I executed some remote script.

The remote script includes the following two aspects:

**1)** The command:

```
wget -P ~/myAddons/ https://raw.githubusercontent.com/user/repo/master/appendix.sh
```

**2)** a `source ~/myAddons/appendix.sh` command:

This file `appendix.sh`, includes some Bash aliases.

---

### The problem

After executing the remote script, I tried to use some aliases from `appendix.sh`. None worked.

Only after manually executing `source ~/myAddons/appendix.sh`, the aliases worked.

- I checked at least 3 times that both the remote script's `source` command, and the manual command, are the same.

### The question

Why did the execution of `source ~/myAddons/appendix.sh` directly from the remote script, fail, while the manually it worked, and what's the right way to cope with that?

Comment: 1) Where is `curl`? 2) I think you've missed a phase of running it, or else missed some explanation about it.

Comment: You're starting a new shell with `bash <(...)` and then sourcing within it. That won't affect the original shell from which you ran `bash <(...)`.

Comment: @muru this could be great as an answer here because it really answered my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're starting a new shell with `bash <(...)` and then sourcing within it. That won't affect the original shell from which you ran `bash <(...)`. You should `source` the process substitution instead:

```
source <(...)
# or
. <(...)
```